# Thymeleaf rendering data inside the template file

Tags: thymeleaf

I have template.html file that contains the layout for all the pages and I have another html file(index.html), I want the data of the index.html file to be written in template.html's body tag. How can I do this through thymeleaf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you would go other way around, and include template, or parts of the template in your page like this:

```
<head th:include="fragments/template :: headFragment">
```

in the header, or

```
<div th:include="fragments/template :: footerFragment"></div>
```

in the body of your index.html. Where fragments are in template.html file:

```
<header id="headerFragment" th:fragment="headerFragment">
...
</header>

<div class="container">
</div>

<footer id="footer" th:fragment="footerFragment">
  <!-- FOOTER -->
  <footer>
    ...
  </footer>
</footer>
```

Once you include index page into your template, it would not be a template anymore, right?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Create a page that will contain a layout that will be shared between pages. Often this will be a template that contains a page header, navigation, a footer, and a spot where your page content will go.

Layout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
   <head>
      <title>Layout page</title>
      <script src="common-script.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
         <h1>My website</h1>
      </header>
      <section layout:fragment="content">
          <p>Page content goes here</p>
      </section>
      <footer>
         <p>My footer</p>
         <p layout:fragment="custom-footer">Custom footer here</p>
      </footer>  
    </body>
  </html>
```

Notice how the layout:fragment attribute was applied to the  and

element in the footer. These are the points in the decorator page that are candidates for replacement by matching fragments in the content pages.
Now, create some content pages.

Content1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorator="Layout.html">
<head>
    <title>Content page 1</title>
    <script src="content-script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section layout:fragment="content">
     <p>This is a paragraph from content page 1</p>
    </section>
    <footer>
      <p layout:fragment="custom-footer">This is some footer content from content page 1</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**reference**:

A dialect for Thymeleaf that allows you to use layout/decorator pages to style your content.
https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect#decorators-and-fragments